# Eclipse error when building Workspace

Tags: eclipse

I am new to Eclipse and I am facing an error. Rather than explaining it with my own words, here is the error :

[image]

Could someone help me with that ? (Please, don't go too fast, as stated I am pretty new to Eclipse)

**EDIT** my plugins list :

[image]

Comment: What plug-ins have you installed into Eclipse? This looks like some third-party plugin that does some sort of code review/cleanup.

Comment: @E-Riz I edited the post to let you know, but as far as I know there is no plugin for code review

Comment: The picture doesn't really tell us what plugins you have installed - those icons aren't very useful without names. :-( Don't you remember what you've installed?

Comment: Oops sorry :/ This is a society computer with a pre-packaged bundle of eclipse, so I can't tell you what's in there. I looked online for an answer, and found that the .pmd file can be the problem. But my .pmd file has nothing in common with .pmd files on the answers ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So ... Basically, I just disabled Checkstyle on the project (right click -> Properties -> Checkstyle) and the problem is gone. I will see what happens and pray for it to work ahah.

Thanks all for your help !

Answer (score 1):

One of those looks like it might be FindBugs. If so, that could be the source of the problem. Try disabling or uninstalling it to see if the problem goes away.

From the About dialog, click the **Installation Details** button, and there, on the **Installed Software** tab select the feature in question and use the **Uninstall...** button to remove it.

If it's not FindBugs it might be PMD. I'm not sure what names they show up as in the Installed Software list, but they're probably not hard to identify.

Comment: I tried to disable it in Window -> Preference -> General -> Startup and shutdown, restarted eclipse, but still got the error.

Comment: That doesn't disable or uninstall a feature, only keeps it from running eagerly on startup. I updated the answer with more details for uninstalling.

Comment: So I uninstalled both with Help -> Installation details -> Installed software, but the problem is still there ...